# error with YouTube player activity

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-gradle-plugin

OK -- I am using Android Studio 3.0 and YouTube API version 3 in my project.
I have added the library/jar files to the project (via this link).
The project compiles.

Here is the weird thing I cannot figure out: When I run the app and select a video, the app says "An error occurred while initializing YouTube player" This happens on device and emulator.

I looked at the IDE, I looked at the logcat and all I find is this error message on the IDE itself:

[image: IDE error of YouTube Activity content]

And I see this in the upper part of the IDE as well:

[image: error for YouTube modue]

What is it that I have done wrong and how can I fix it so I can play the YouTube videos when they are selected?

I have added my YouTube activity file code here:

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;

import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;


public class YouTubePlaybackOverlayActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

    private static String ytUrl;
    public String TAG = YouTubePlaybackOverlayActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    public VideoView mVideoView;

    public LeanbackPlaybackState mPlaybackState = LeanbackPlaybackState.IDLE;

    public static final String API_KEY = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

    private int mPosition = 0;
    private long mStartTimeMillis;
    private long mDuration = -1;
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    //private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

//        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
//        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
//        client.connect();
//        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
//                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
//                "PlaybackOverlay Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
//                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
//                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
//                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
//                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
//                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
//                Uri.parse("android-app://software.blackstone.sunnahstreamtv/http/host/path")
//        );
//        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

//        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
//        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
//        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
//                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
//                "PlaybackOverlay Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
//                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
//                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
//                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
//                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
//                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
//                Uri.parse("android-app://software.blackstone.sunnahstreamtv/http/host/path")
//        );
//        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
//        client.disconnect();
    }

    /*
     * List of various states that we can be in
     */
    public enum LeanbackPlaybackState {
        PLAYING, PAUSED, IDLE
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        /** attaching layout xml **/
        //setContentView(R.layout.nabawi_video);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_playback_overlay);
        setContentView(R.layout.video_playback);

        /** Initializing YouTube player view **/
        YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_player);
        youTubePlayerView.initialize(API_KEY, this);
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        //client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }


//    @Override
//    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//        setContentView(R.layout.activity_playback_overlay);
//
//        loadViews();
//    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        stopPlayback();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void loadViews() {
        mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_player);
        mVideoView.setFocusable(false);
        mVideoView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);

        Movie movie = (Movie) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(DetailsActivity.MOVIE);
        //setVideoPath(movie.getVideoUrl());
        setVideoPath(movie.getyTubeID());
        ytUrl = movie.getyTubeID();
    }

    public void setVideoPath(String videoUrl) {
        setPosition(0);
        mVideoView.setVideoPath(videoUrl);
        mStartTimeMillis = 0;
        mDuration = Utils.getDuration(videoUrl);
    }

    private void stopPlayback() {
        if (mVideoView != null) {
            mVideoView.stopPlayback();
        }
    }

    private void setPosition(int position) {
        if (position > mDuration) {
            mPosition = (int) mDuration;
        } else if (position < 0) {
            mPosition = 0;
            mStartTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        } else {
            mPosition = position;
        }
        mStartTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Log.d(TAG, "position set to " + mPosition);
    }

    public int getPosition() {
        return mPosition;
    }

    public void setPlaybackState(LeanbackPlaybackState playbackState) {
        this.mPlaybackState = playbackState;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_playback_overlay, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void playPause(boolean doPlay) {
        if (mPlaybackState == LeanbackPlaybackState.IDLE) {
            /* Callbacks for mVideoView */
            setupCallbacks();
        }

        if (doPlay && mPlaybackState != LeanbackPlaybackState.PLAYING) {
            mPlaybackState = LeanbackPlaybackState.PLAYING;
            if (mPosition > 0) {
                mVideoView.seekTo(mPosition);
            }
            mVideoView.start();
            mStartTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        } else {
            mPlaybackState = LeanbackPlaybackState.PAUSED;
            int timeElapsedSinceStart = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() - mStartTimeMillis);
            setPosition(mPosition + timeElapsedSinceStart);
            mVideoView.pause();
        }
    }

    public void fastForward() {
        if (mDuration != -1) {
            // Fast forward 10 seconds.
            setPosition(mVideoView.getCurrentPosition() + (10 * 1000));
            mVideoView.seekTo(mPosition);
        }
    }

    public void rewind() {
        // rewind 10 seconds
        setPosition(mVideoView.getCurrentPosition() - (10 * 1000));
        mVideoView.seekTo(mPosition);
    }

    private void setupCallbacks() {

        mVideoView.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                mVideoView.stopPlayback();
                mPlaybackState = LeanbackPlaybackState.IDLE;
                return false;
            }
        });

        mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                if (mPlaybackState == LeanbackPlaybackState.PLAYING) {
                    mVideoView.start();
                }
            }
        });

        mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mPlaybackState = LeanbackPlaybackState.IDLE;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult result) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failured to Initialize!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
        /** add listeners to YouTubePlayer instance **/
        player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(playerStateChangeListener);
        player.setPlaybackEventListener(playbackEventListener);
        player.setFullscreen(true);
        player.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS);
        //player.play();


        /** Start buffering **/

        for (int i = 0; i < MovieProvider.mItems.size(); i++) {
            Movie movie = (Movie) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(DetailsActivity.MOVIE);
            player.loadVideo(movie.getyTubeID());
        }

    }

    private YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener playbackEventListener = new YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onBuffering(boolean arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPaused() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPlaying() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onSeekTo(int arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopped() {
        }

    };

    private YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener playerStateChangeListener = new YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAdStarted() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaded(String arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoading() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onVideoEnded() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onVideoStarted() {
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was a corrout indexing in the project.
I removed the class file.
Then I cleared the cache, restarted Android Studio and then cleaned and rebuilt the project.
I restarted Android Studio again and then recreated the desired class file(s) and layout files and the project compiled successfully and everything is good.

Thanks everyone for your time, advice, advice and input.